# Name of Colon Character Usage in an if-then-else Javascript Expression

Tags: javascript

I'm reading through Speaking Javascript and in Chapter 1. Basic Javascript under [Statements Versus Expressions](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch01.html#_an_overview_of_the_syntax) this example is used, but it is not apparent to me what the colon (`y :`) presents.

```
var x = y >= 0 ? y : -y;
```

In the example, `>=` is an equality operator.  Does the `:` have a similar name for its use here?

*Edit:* I previously asked how to read this out loud and it was labeled as opinion based.  Hopefully asking for the name of the character usage is a question with a more objective answer.

Comment: If you understand what the code does, why is it necessary to have others tell you how to state that out loud? You're own interpretation is what matters.

Comment: As I'm re-reading the question 30 minutes later, you can see one reason -- my own interpretation was not correct.  `? y : -y;` is not "otherwise set y to negative y"; we're not setting var y at any point.  There are good and valuable reasons to be able to convert syntax to natural language (e.g. peer discussion).

Comment: @tommy_o Well, you could run that through the console. Whoever wrote that function in that ternary way wanted to be super smart and tricky. y >= 0 ? y : -y; More readable would be if( y is bigger or equal than 0 ) { x = y} else (the y: means nothing, the ":" means here comes the else clause) {set x to -y} or plain JS :
 if( y>= 0 ) { x = y} else {x = -y}

Comment: You're missing the minimal conditional parenthesis and I recommend using the fully enclosing parenthesis, example: `var x = ((y >= 0) ? y : -y);`.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  From these comments I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator which concisely explains what I needed.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say it like this:

- Set the variable x to y if y is greater than or equal to 0 or to -y if not.
- If y is 0, set x to y else set x to -y.
- Using a conditional operator make X y if y is greater than or equal to 0 or -y elsewise.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still hung up on what the colon is representing in `y :` but Ill keep at it using the first and second bullet point to find something that works for me personally.  Thanks again.

Comment: Got it from this plus the other comments -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator.  Thanks!